# Better approach to design sub-menu for item management menu

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation

This is a question for item management. (By item, I mean any item such as a user, product, etc.)

Which approach is better?

1. an item management menu containing options to create, delete, search/view, edit
2. having separate modes to create items and search for items, where the user selects an item from the search results to view, edit or delete selected item

**EDIT :**

This is an example :

[image]

With only a "search" page, the rest "view", "edit", and "delete" functionality can also be applied.

But, will the user know this flow? Is it enough with only "create" and "search" menu?

Or the menu really should say "Create Item", "Search/View Item", "Search/Edit Item", "Search/Delete Item" ???

Comment: Can you explain what you mean (for both cases) using a small mockup?

Comment: What's the context of usage? What are the user goals? What sort of tasks they may perform? How often? How many items are involved?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I added an example image related to browse(search) page. The create item page should be clear enough, that the page will contain a create form, therefore I don't post an update about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From professional experience, I'd recommend two categories: create and search.

If you want to view, edit, or delete something, your average user will first need to search for it.  If you give all 5 options: search, view, edit, delete, and create; it's unclear the order of actions the user must take.  Do I go to the delete page, then the search page for an item to delete it? Or do I need to go to the search page first, then go to the delete page once I found the right item?

Having two simple options, create and search, is extremely clear and more importantly concise.  If I want to create a new item, there will be no doubt which option to choose.  If I want to edit or delete an item, it's also just as clear, since "create" isn't valid, it must be search, which also follows the normal path I mentioned above where users search for something first and THEN take an action on it.

The only exception to this case is for power users.  It's theoretically possible they could already have a list of IDs and simply want to paste them somewhere to take some action (edit, delete, etc.).  Though you could still cater to these users by allowing bulk actions on the search page, so along with having an edit and delete button on every row, provide bulk edit or bulk delete options at the top of the page with check boxes on each row.

Comment: thank you very much for your clear explanation. your reason boost a great confidence to the design :) I wish I could upvote this answer, but my rep points clearly say no :/